# How can we add custom button in Microsoft team

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, microsoft-teams

Is there any way to add a custom button in Microsoft team channel to open a popup where we can do the insert operations with SharePoint list?

Below is screenshot example:

[image]

Comment: If you're looking to extend the menus with your own command (like a listview commandset in SPFx) then that is unfortunately not an option in Teams.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Microsoft Teams Tabs using SharePoint Framework (SPFx).

Follow below Microsoft official documentations which explains how to create Microsoft Teams Tabs using SharePoint Framework (SPFx):

1. [Building Microsoft Teams Tabs using SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/integrate-with-teams-introduction)
2. [Build Microsoft Teams tab using SharePoint Framework - Tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab)